# EC2 instance stops working after running supervisorctl update command laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, supervisord

So I just faced this issue second time. First time I stopped that instance and created a new one as I coudn't resove it but happend the same in the second instance.

I was working on the Laravel queue and had to make the jobs run automatically so as per their document below I followed the steps.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

As soon as I run the "sudo supervisorctl update" command the whole instance stops working. SSH is also stop working so not sure how to resolve this issue.

The installation of supervisor and adding the laravel-worker.conf file works fine. Also the "sudo supervisorctl reread" works fine but as soon I run the update command, the whole instance stops working.

Please help.

updaing the Laravel-worker

```
[program:laravel-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/mydomain.com/artisan queue:work
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubuntu
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/mydomain.com/worker.log​
```

Comment: You should post your `laravel-worker.conf` also what ec2 instance type are you using?

Comment: @Second2None I have updated the question with laravel-worker.conf file and I am using t2.micro instance. I have replaced the domain name with "mydomain.com".

Comment: `numprocs=8`  is quite high for a micro instance. You can try to limit this to 1 or 2 and see if it improves. Also make sure this path actually exists `/var/www/mydomain.com/`

Comment: @Second2None yes the live website was already running there but now everything is stopped. Not sure how to change the numprocs=8 because I cannot even connect to instance using SSH.

Comment: You'll need to most likely reboot the instance.  Or you can try connecting via the EC2 dashboard, sometimes that works.

Comment: @Second2None I tried it already but still the same. Also tried to stop and start the instance again but the same.

Comment: I wouldn't spend too much time working out instance issues you could spend hours with not much progress. Ditch that one and start up a new one and see if the changes help. If it doesn't it could be a permissions issue.

Comment: I have already created the new instance and setup everything and make the site live again in that. Now I will have to do it third time.

Comment: You shouldn't be testing on your production server mate. Set up a staging site. Production should be stable.

Comment: I have the paid AWS support so I will wait until they reply and let you know.

Comment: @AlbertScott was this issue ever resolved?